# Trying to check if a certain position contains a certain character in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I need to check the third and fourth last position of a string if it contains a dot. I'm unsure how to do this. Do I use string.Contains for this? Do I need to make an Array out of it? I'm thoroughly confused about this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show us what you tried so far?

Comment: To check if there is a specified _character_ at a given location _may_ be more tricky than you may expect but we'd like to see, at least, a basic attempt and some reasoning about it. Code to do it is pretty similar to what you describe in plain words...

Comment: It will be good to give an example what exactly you want. For example I have string "Test...String..Hell.O.World" and what you want to return. Also show your effort.

Comment: `bool ok = meStr[meStr.Length - 4] =='.' || meStr[meStr.Length - 5] == '.';`

Comment: @Bidou notice he used the word 'last'.

Comment: @Bidou that is wrong ! First he asks for the **third and fourth last position**, ans second s[3] is the 4th position (0,1,2,3) not the third... so s[4] would be the 5th char

Comment: @m.rogalski this might crash, so needs validation as well (defensive programming).

Comment: char[] nameArray = name.ToCharArray();
                if (Char.IsUpper(nameArray[0]))
                {
                    int antal = 0; 
                    for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (name[i] == '-')
                            antal++;

Comment: @L-Four i know because `meStr.Length < 4 || meStr.Length < 5` but that was not the question.

Comment: That's messy. Uh. That's what I have. Unsure how to format that. But basically, that's what I have, say I want to check if name contains a "." as the third and fourth last character.

Comment: @m.rogalski But it is a mandatory part of the solution, for sure.

Comment: @L-Four nope. He was asking only for the part that i've provided.

Comment: Please @m.rogalski, a defensive developer would add it to the solution, it was maybe not asked explicitely but as I said should be part of the solution. Best practice!

Comment: @L-Four If your requirement in  company is to create method for addition ( a + b ) would you do addition or addition and subtraction ( a - b ) because it seems reasonable? And I dont care if someone like you says that i'm "bad developer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for *absolute position*, so `Contains` won't do, but `[..]` and `Length`:

```
  string myString = "dots . dots and .dot";

  int index = 4; // one based
  char charToTest = '.';

  // if index'th character is charToTest:
  //  1. the string is long enough 
  //  2. it has charToTest at Length - index position
  if (myString.Length >= index && 
      myString[myString.Length - index] == charToTest) {
    ... 
  }
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

yourString.IndexOf(".", yourString.Length - 5, 2) != -1

Comment: Counter example: `"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.z"`

Comment: I fully agree, my "answer" was lazy at best, but please note that I didn't try to counter your well formed answer. It hadn't loaded by the time I wrote mine.